# Replace a string "" with nothing

Tags: c#

I have the input .txt file which is like

```
"ABC","","","","DEF",""
```

but the output of the .txt should look like

```
"ABC",,,,"DEF",
```

The C# code has to remove the empty "" with nothing. I am new to C#, not sure how can this be done.Can anybody help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `"ABC","","","","DEF",""` looks more like a collection of strings rather than a single string. Which is it?

Comment: I get a word file with text in that which looks similar to this.

Comment: So you get "" as part of the text

Comment: `var newString = oldString.Replace( "\"\"", string.Empty);`

Comment: Yes I get "" as a part of the text.

Comment: That doesn't really look like a word file. It really looks like a CSV file, and you should read it properly - a proper CSV parser should interpret the `""` as an empty string.

Comment: It is a comma delimited text file

Comment: @user2698249 - Then you should definitely look into a proper CSV parser. Reading CSV is very easy for a lot of cases, but there are some huge pitfalls in other cases. So instead of trying to figure them all out by yourself, use the brainpower others have already put into it. ^_^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to replace verbatim `""` with nothing.

To do so, you need to escape the quotes like this: `input.Replace("\"\"", "");`

Here's a code sample that you can run from a Console app.

```
string input = "\"ABC\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"DEF\",\"\"";

Console.WriteLine(input); // Prints "ABC","","","","DEF",""

string output = input.Replace("\"\"", "");

Console.WriteLine(output); // Prints "ABC",,,,"DEF",
```